# What is the difference between --init-file and --rcfile?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I've been working with bash, and I came across the `--rcfile` and `--init-file` options. Bash's man page lists these under the same section, but they seem to behave differently. Take the following scenario:

I have created a `~/.bash_profile` which has the following command:

```
exec env -i <variables> /bin/bash <option> ~/.bashrc
```

for the purposes of a project which require the terminal to open with a specific configuration; it is instructed not to read `/etc/bash.bashrc` and instead only read from `~/.bashrc`. If `<option>` is --init-file, `~/.bashrc` is read without error. However, `--rcfile` in its place does not appear to source the file.

What is the difference between these two seemingly identical commands?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are synonymous.

From the `shell.c` file of `bash`-4.3 source:

```
long_args[] = {
....
  { "init-file", Charp, (int *)0x0, &bashrc_file },
....
  { "rcfile", Charp, (int *)0x0, &bashrc_file },
....
};
```

As you can see they are defined the same way and also works the same way.

The parameter `bashrc_file` stores the filename.

For further assurance, the `CHANGES` file in the source contains:

> Added a new '--init-file' invocation argument as a synonym for
>   '--rcfile', per the new GNU coding standards.

Comment: But then why would it work one way but not the other?

Comment: @BHustus They should behave in the same way, i have tested couple of times too with various possible factors but they always behave the same way for me..

Comment: Huh... I'll look back into it.